# Get browser URL with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

That take the current browser url

How can i paste the pathname into an html element like a p tag?

Comment: Cool. What did you try and what happens?

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
$('p.class').html(location.pathname);
```

If you want to get the full URL:

```
$('p.class').html(location.href);
```

Comment: FYI -- If one wanted to get the URL rather than the PATH, one could use `locaiton.href`.

Comment: That's right, but if you just want the path name (for this page it'd be `/questions/9948212/jquery-get-browser-url-and-insert-into-html-element`), you'd use this